# How do I close the jFrame of my JList?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listselectionlistener

I have a JList problem. I have listeners for this JList (both mouse and keyboard).
I would like, after you double clicked on one of the option of the list (or pressed Enter), that the JFrame closes. I couldn't find that anywhere. Could you please help me with that?

Here's the class that I use (taken from StackOverflow):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Vector;

public class ActionJList extends JList {

  ActionListener al;
  boolean close=false;

  public ActionJList(String[] it){
    super(it);

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        if (al == null) return;
        Object ob[] = getSelectedValues();
        if (ob.length > 1) return;
        if (me.getClickCount() == 2) {
          System.out.println("Sending ACTION_PERFORMED to ActionListener");
          al.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this,
          ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED,
          ob[0].toString()));
          me.consume();
          close=true;

        }
      }
    });

    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
        if (al == null) return;
        Object ob[] = getSelectedValues();
        if (ob.length > 1) return;
        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
          System.out.println("Sending ACTION_PERFORMED to ActionListener");
          al.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this,
          ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED,
          ob[0].toString()));
          ke.consume();
        } 
      }
    });
    this.setSelectedIndex(0); 
  }

  public ActionJList(Vector it){
    super(it);

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        if (al == null) return;
        Object ob[] = getSelectedValues();
        if (ob.length > 1) return;
        if (me.getClickCount() == 2) {
          System.out.println("Sending ACTION_PERFORMED to ActionListener");
          al.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this,
          ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED,
          ob[0].toString()));
          me.consume();
        }
      }
    });

    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
        if (al == null) return;
        Object ob[] = getSelectedValues();
        if (ob.length > 1) return;
        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
          System.out.println("Sending ACTION_PERFORMED to ActionListener");
          al.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this,
          ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED,
          ob[0].toString()));
          ke.consume();
        } 
      }
    });
    this.setSelectedIndex(0); 
  }



  public void addActionListener(ActionListener al){
    this.al = al;
  }
  public boolean getClose(){return close;}
}
```

Comment: Was the code that badly indented when you found it on SO?

Answer (score 3):

You can always use the following snippet:

```
Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(ActionJList.this);
if (window!=null)
    window.setVisible(false);
```

NB: instead of adding a `KeyListener/KeyAdapter` to your `JList`, consider using Swing KeyBindings.

Comment: +1 for using the SwingUtilities class which has many helpful methods.

Comment: Very nice, didn't realise this  functionality was available.

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth check out [List Action](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/list-action/) for a reusable class that adds the MouseListener and Key Bindings for you. Also, the source of the event is the JList so it makes it easy for you to create your Action using Guillaume's suggestion.

There is no need to make a reference to the JFrame available. The SwingUtilities approach is the better way.